# Method Signatures in Generic Map Interface

Tags: java, generics, collections, dictionary

I have just studied Generics in Java via Oracle Docs Tutorial[Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). Now I have moved on to Collections Framework. I want to know that if Map interface is generic like this

```
 public interface Map<K,V> {

    // Basic operations
    V put(K key, V value);
    V get(Object key);
    V remove(Object key);
    boolean containsKey(Object key);
//some more method declarations
}
```

I want to know that why method signature of `V get(Object key); V remove(Object key);      boolean containsKey(Object key);` use Object as its argument and not K.

Comment: @MattBall disagree; in fact, the answer is MUCH more obvious than what the linked question explains

Comment: @fge you disagree that this question is a duplicate? ...Really?

Answer (score 3):

This is because the keys of a `Map` are ultimately a `Set`; and a `Map` contains a value for a given key if its `Set` of keys [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) the queried value...

... And you will notice, from the prototype of the `contains()` method linked above, that this method's argument is an `Object`! Which is understandable; while, for instance, some implementations of `Set` will relies on `.equals()` (whose argument is an `Object`), some other implementations rely on the argument implementing `Comparable`. There is just no common "lower type" to these two possible implementations than `Object`...

As a further indication, you will notice that a `Map`'s [`keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) is true to its name: it returns a `Set`...

(out of sheer curiosity, if you dig into the code, you will notice that a `HashSet` is in fact a `HashMap`; it is just that you don't have access to the values of the map. A `HashSet` is quite a costly thing to use, ultimately!)

Comment: As I said in my other comment, `Comparable` is unrelated to the contract of `contains`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is some explanation in Collection API - *...many methods in Collections Framework interfaces are defined in terms of the equals method...*. Object.equals does not require the objects be of the same type. Eg an ArrayList may be equal to a LinkedList.

Comment: Partial explanation only; consider a `SortedSet`!

Comment: @fge Not really. Ordering (based on `Comparable` or a specified `Comparator`) is merely an additional contract and always requires consistency with `equals`.